# How do I add/replace something at the top of each file of a type (Sublime)

Tags: regex, templates, replace, sublimetext3

I want to add a tag at the start of each `.tpl` file. How do I do this in Sublime?

Existing file example **some-file.tpl**:

```
1: {def "hello" key="hello"} // Every file starts like this.
2: {def "world" key="world"}
3: ...
```

I have tried this RegEx for Find and Replace:

```
Find: (\{def){1}
Where: *.tpl
Replace: @@def\n\1
```

Expected **outcome** some-file.tpl:

```
1: @@def
2: {def "hello" key="hello"} 
3: {def "world" key="world"}
```

But the above RegEx also matches the other `{def` in the same file even though I am limiting using `{1}`. I just want to match the `{def` from the first line so that I can add a tag there.

Is there any other way to add something to the start of each file.

Comment: Writing a `{1}` quantifier is totally useless. Each character or group in a regex pattern occur once. Adding `{1}` doesn't limit anything, it's just redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

*Find*: `(?s)\A.*`
*Replace*: `@@def\n$&`

where `(?s)\A.*` matches the start of the file and then any 0+ chars up to the file end, and this text will get appended to the inserted value with the help of the `$&` backreference.

*EDIT*: To match any .tpl document starting with `{def`, use `(?s)\A\{def.*` in *Find* field.

[image]

Comment: This works. Is there a way to match only the files which start with `{def` and not all .tpl files?

Comment: Yes, just use `(?s)\A\{def.*` pattern.